# AWS lambda capture IoT thing creation event

Tags: aws-iot, aws

I need to perform some additional operation when new **thing** created in **AWS IOT** , to accomplish this requirement needed to trigger a **Lambda** function upon new thing creation event.

I followed [AWS lambda capture IoT registry event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52865956/aws-lambda-capture-iot-registry-event), but not able to captured the event and also lambda was not triggered when I created a new thing.

Is it required to add any **policies** or **role** to capture the event? Or else any alternate way is there to capture the event?

Comment: Could you able to achieve this functionality? Can you provide any reference link for same.